# Vim forgetting its history when a file becomes read-only

Tags: vim, undo

After I commit a file to Perforce with vi, it will become read-only.

If I have this file open in vim, then when it becomes readonline I lose my undo-redo history, without even being asked.

Is there an option in VI to preserve the undo-redo history when the file becomes read only while you are editing?

Comment: What version of vim are you using and what platform (windows, linux, etc)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that in the question.

I'm using gvim 7.0 on Win XP. (not using Windows by choice...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Vim bug.  Whenever you `:edit filename`, implicitly or explicitly it seams that Vim is zeroing all undo history for this file because ( I guess ) it think that it is newly opened file.  And after perforce commit, your file is kind of “changed outside” and Vim should ask you “Reload file?” unless you set “autoread”.

Check you vimrc for “set autoread” option.

Comment: Thank you!

I indeed had "set autoread" in my vimrc.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to make it readable with modelines :

```
#vim : set noreadonly:
```

I wrote # but of course you must replace it with the adequate symbol for a comment.